# Embedding problems with Tensorflow : Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Tags: r, tensorflow, embedding

I have troubles finding the source of this error:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

The model is trained and runs perfect. But when I need to extract the embeddings I have no idea what goes wrong. The error happens at the last line.

This is the code:

```
embedding_matrix <- get_weights(model)[[1]]

words <- data_frame(
  word = names(tokenizer$word_index), 
  id = as.integer(unlist(tokenizer$word_index))
)

words <- words %>%
  filter(id <= tokenizer$num_words) %>%
  arrange(id)

row.names(embedding_matrix) <- c("UNK", words$word)
```